# How do I write date, time, serial, part, etc... to csv file using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, file-processing

The code works properly upto entering for loop and the date values is fetched. after that it returns an empty list of values for rest of the variables like time, ref1, seriel and all.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# Create a Dataframe from CSV
my_dataframe = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/WI/Desktop/file.csv')

# Drop rows with any empty cells
my_dataframe.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=['date'], inplace=False)

with open("C:/Users/WDSI/Desktop/OutputFile.txt", "w") as F:
    F.write("%s" %my_dataframe)  

fin = open("C:/Users/WDSI/Desktop/OutputFile.txt", "r")
# print("Input file is taken")
fout = open("C:/Users/WDSI/Desktop/OutputFile1.txt", "w")
# print("Output file is taken")
for line in fin:
    date = re.findall(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', fin.read())
    time = re.findall(r'(\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})',fin.read())
    seriel=re.findall(r'(\s[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9])',fin.read())
    part=re.findall(r'(\s[0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])',fin.read())
    ref1=re.findall(r'(\s\d{16})',fin.read())
    ref3=re.findall(r'(\d{9})+$',fin.read())
    #print(date)
    #print(time)
    #print(seriel)
    #print(part)
    #print(ref1)
    #print(ref3)
    fout.write("%10s,%8s" %((date,time)))
    fout.close()
```

when we run this code only date variable gets the value other variables like time, ref1 and all goes empty. also please help me to write date,time,serial,part,ref1,ref3 from each row of csv file. in this format the output file should be written.

Comment: As you use 'w' when write, your for loop is writing the first line and then immediately closed it.  So what will happen to other lines? Your closing file method should sit out of the loop also you should use 'w+' or append after first loop..

Comment: Do you absolutely need to get data in this manner? or is it acceptable for you to get it from the dataframe?

Comment: dataframe is written into a file. from that i am trying to get it. Is there any other way to get it directly from dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not exact replica of your solution but that how you can open a file and take whatever you need from each line then write the new data to a new file.

I have catered a csv file with the following lines:

```
This is a date 2019-08-05, 2019-09-03
This is a email asdfasdf@abc.com
```

## Solution 1:

```
with open("./Datalake/output.txt", "w+") as wf:
    with open("./Datalake/test.csv") as f:
        for line in f:
            dates = re.findall(r"\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}", line)
            dates = "|".join(dates)
            emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', line)
            emails = "|".join(emails)
            extracted_line = "{}, {}\n".format(dates, emails)
            wf.write(extracted_line)
            print(extracted_line)
```

## Solution 2:

You can extract directly from data frame. Apply the same search using a lambda function which will execute for each row. But be careful you might need some error handling lambda function will through error if there is None value in the column. Convert the column to `str` before applying lambda.

```
df = pd.read_csv("./Datalake/test.csv", sep='\n', header=None, names=["string_col"])
df['dates'] = df["string_col"].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}", x))
df['emails'] = df["string_col"].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+", x))
```

In that case the calculated column will a python list so you might consider to use `''.join()` in the lambda to make them text.

Comment: what if we want to check in the first value of each row should contain something and 2nd value of row shouldnt empty? before fetching by using regex

Comment: Can you give an example with data. I do not understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: 1st ROW---> Name Date  seriel ref1          ref2
2nd ROW--->ABC 2019-10-14 aaa      161651 151111
3rd ROW--->BBG EMPTY          hju      656565 565626
4th ROW--->ABC 2019-12-09   jjj       656566 232323
5th ROW--->ABC EMPTY   kjjfk       986547 321455                                                   in this just want to fetch only ABC row , but if the date is missing in the relevant row we have to omit that row. hope u have  got it now.

Comment: i just wanna add the condition with your solution1

Comment: @sharvaa after extracting date you can put a if else statement before to use the join function with date: `if len(date) > 0 and 'abc' in line: ...` and put rest of the code under the if `else pass` . The `if` will go the the second line in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading line by line with the `for line in fin` but the first all your `findall` read the whole file content with `fin.read()`.

You either process line by line (replace those `fin.read()` with `line`):

```
for line in fin:
    date = re.findall(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', line)
    ...
```

Or read the whole file and remove the `for`:

```
content = f.read()
date = re.findall(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', content)
...
```

Comment: Thanks luis. Even after removing the for loop line from the code i get the same problem.

Comment: or part works luis, thank you. and please help me to get only 9 digit number from the file. where my ref3 line fetches another 9digit values too from 16 digits

Comment: Now i fetched all the values at once. Now i just wanna write them into a file , i tried with #fout.write("%10s,%8s" %((date,time,seriel,part,ref1,ref2)))
#fout.write("'{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}'" .format((date,time,seriel,part,ref1,ref2))) but both doesnt work